# Select all records created or modified after a specific date in all tables in a SQL Server db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I would like a list of all new or modified records created after a specific date in all tables in a SQL Server database.

I am using SQL Server 2005 and ssms.

Is there a way to do this with one query, or some other tool?

How could I do this for one table?

Comment: Someone smarter than me will confirm, but I think to get a RECORD level log of modified date/times, you need to maintain a field for it.  Metadata only saves modified date/times for objects like tables/views/storedprocs.

Comment: Does your table **have** a datetime column that stores the date of creation and last modification??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all the tables have a ModifiedDate date column, you can then use the undocumented `sp_msforeachtable` proc

```
sp_msforeachtable 'select ''?'',count(*) 
   from ? where ModifiedDate > ''20100101'''
```

Just adjust the date range, I also use count(*) because I doubt you want millions of rows returned to you

If you don't have a column then you are out of luck, or if the column is named differently in every table then you need to use dynamic sql together with `information_schema.columns` and `information_schema.tables` to construct this query

Comment: +1 for sp_msforerachtable.  I use that a lot, with sp_msforeachdb to check all tables in all dbs on a server.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherent in SQL Server where you can get that information.  As @JNK indicated, you have to build that into your database design.  And, you have to build the solution for each table by adding the create date as a column.  Then, you can use SQL to capture the information.